# Why adding third inputbox gives [NoSuchElementException: None.get]

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

```
val createUserForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "username" -> text,
    "password" -> text,
    "role" -> text
  )
)

def createUser = Action { implicit request ⇒
  var (username, password, role) = createUserForm.bindFromRequest.get
  println(username, password, role)
}
```

Gives me `NoSuchElementException: None.get`, but if I remove `role`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to call `Option.get`. You need to handle the case that `bindFromRequest` returns `None`.

You could use [`Option.fold(ifEmpty)(f)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@fold[B]%28ifEmpty:=%3EB%29%28f:A=%3EB%29:B) or `Option.map(f).getOrElse(ifEmpty)`.

```
def createUser = Action { implicit request =>
  createUserForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    println("You need to enter all the fields.")
  ){ case (username, password, role) =>
    println(username, password, role)
  }
}
```